# PainterResource throws IllegalArgumentException: Only VectorDrawables and rasterized asset types are supported

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I am working on a Jetpack Project which downloads an image from API using Coil Library.

I have confirmed that valid image URLs and related data are being returned from the API call successfully. I am able to view the image on my browser using the returned URL.

This is my Image Composable:

```
@Composable
fun AstroPhoto(picture: AstroPicture) {

    val imgUrl = picture.url.toUri()
            .buildUpon()
            .scheme("https")
            .build()
    
    AsyncImage(model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .data(imgUrl)
            .size(Size.ORIGINAL)
            .crossfade(true).build(),

            placeholder = painterResource(R.drawable.loading_animation),
            contentDescription = picture.title,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    )
}
```

I call the above image composable in a Lazy Column:

```
....
 Box( ... ) {
            
           LazyColumn(content = {
               
               items(state.astroPictures) {
               
                AstroPhoto(picture = it)
            } })
            
        }
```

This is the exception at I am getting:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.uxstate, PID: 31790
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only VectorDrawables and
> rasterized asset types are supported ex. PNG, JPG
> at androidx.compose.ui.res.PainterResources_androidKt.loadVectorResource(PainterResources.android.kt:93)

I am on `compose_version = '1.1.1'` working with `kotlin_version = '1.6.10'`. My coil version is `"io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.1.0"` and `compileSdk 32` and AS Chipmunk. Source code can be found [here](https://github.com/Tonnie-Dev/AsteroidsInCompose).

I have checked the docs and searched online but cannot resolve the error. Please help me to go about the error, Thanks.

Comment: I have used [This](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/resources#animated-vector-drawables) . Though its loading the animation but placeholder is only being visible right before image was loaded . Not sure why (i tried loading a 2 MB image to test with cache disabled) ..

Comment: @ADM Good Tip, the error is now gone but the image is not animated as anticipated.

Comment: Something new??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a Jetpack Compose bug

For the time being I've been able to fix this issue in my own project by using an AndroidView to render an ImageView.

In the case of you needing to asynchronously load images, you could render a Glide imageview or something similar

```
fun AppImage(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    @DrawableRes resource: Int,
    colorFilter: ColorFilter? = null
) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { context ->
        ImageView(context).apply {
            setImageResource(resource)
            setColorFilter(colorFilter?.asAndroidColorFilter())
        }
    },
        update = {
            it.setImageResource(resource)
            it.colorFilter = colorFilter?.asAndroidColorFilter()
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just encountered this error and see if anyone had the same error as me.

I just re-opened the Android Studio, and after that, I use Clean Project and Rebuild Project. Now the project and the compose preview are working fine.

Comment: Same here! Before you try any crazy workarounds, see if a simple restart fixes it.

Comment: but it happens for real users for release builds https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78153985/jetpack-compose-displaying-adaptive-icon-painter-resources-only-vectordrawables

Answer (score 7):

My project worked correctly before, but after I changed some code (just add a fucntion, it is not about png or jpg or other things about image), my app crash when render a png. But after i reinstall the project in the emulator, it is fixed.
It seems like a bug in Compose? I dont know, may be a bug in gradle?
**Just try to reinstall your app**, i think it will be fixed.

Comment: `Sync Project with Gradle FIles` after `SHIFT x 2` worked for me.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using png and jpg with painterResource but still face this issue. Change your image, It happened when there is something wrong with the image.

painterResource converts png, and jpg in the bitmap. Its throws that error if it fails to convert any Resource

Comment: This seems to only happens on certain devices as opposed to it being the image, which would means its a jetpack compose bug

Answer (score 1):

Tried to use `shape` drawable as a placeholder and it caused this error.

If I set the same placeholder to `ImageRequest.Builder` instead, the code works fine.

```
AsyncImage(
    model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
        .data(imageUrl)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_rect)
        .error(R.drawable.placeholder_rect)
        .build(),
    contentDescription = "",
)
```

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that the image was 187 MB and the app was running into an OutOfMemoryError. I had to use Glide and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75589193/12528345) answer to scale the image before loading it.

Answer (score 1):

```
allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 7MB until OOM"

                                                   
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only VectorDrawables and rasterized asset types are supported ex. PNG, JPG
```

**Simple solve:** set image for lower size! its out of memory!

Or maby u call many screens in compose or other!

Answer (score 1):

#### TLDR

Probably, you have conflicting xml declarations.

#### Details

I had this project structure

**design-system**

- `ic_circle.xml` (This is an svg drawable)

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <group>
        <clip-path android:pathData="M0,0h24v24h-24z" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#191C1E"
            android:pathData="M12,12m-8,0a8,8 0,1 1,16 0a8,8 0,1 1,-16 0" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

But I use that resource from another module

**app**

- `ic_circle.xml` (This is a shape drawable)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/background" />
</shape>
```

Removing conflicting xml file resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

in my previous projects, there is no problem passing drawable resources to painterResource function. But when I create a new jetpack-compose project, the problem you describe occurs.

In my new project, this problem only happens in preview phase. When I firstly build and run my app in emulator, the problem suddenly disappears.

so this is my solution: **if you haven't run you app in emulator, build and run it in emulator**.

Comment: Based on the detail in the question and comments, I think this is related to the animation of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Solved restarting Android Studio, and clean an rebuild works too

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have some PNG and Webp image formats.

Right-click on each image and convert it to the same format. Then I also have to invalidate cache and restart to make it work.