# Jetpack Compose App crashed when updated from previous version

Tags: android, exception, android-jetpack-compose, android-vectordrawable

My app crashes when updated from previous version with Exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only VectorDrawables and rasterized asset types are supported ex. PNG, JPG

It runs fine when new version is fresh installed. The problem only occurs when it is updated from older version. It crashes on my second activity where I show image from drawables folder, the launcher activity works just fine.

This is how I show drawable image:

`Image( painter = painterResource(id = myDataClass.iconResId), contentDescription = "" )`

`myDataClass` is a data object, upon every app start I initialize `iconResId` propery with xml drawable resource id (since it can change on every app launch).

I have done upgrading properly:
versionCode of new apk is greater than old apk
versionName is also different string.

Might be worth noting, There are couple of extra drawables added in new version but none of old ones removed.

Tried debugging and checking if resource id is properly initialized in `iconResId` propery. It is being initialized properly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72582702/painterresource-throws-illegalargumentexception-only-vectordrawables-and-raster Check this issue

Comment: @KamilJeglikowski Yes I checked this before posting the question, reinstalling fixes the issue, but I need to upload my app to play store where users will upgrade from previous version, when this upgrade happens it crashes, otherwise if fresh installed it runs without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check your file in `drawable` because if it is regular image with xml tags such as `<shape/>`, `<layer-list/>` etc - then you can't use it in Jetpack Compose. You should use .png/.jpg/.webp and other supported extensions or svg image imported through `Vector Asset` tool

Attach you image/file under `iconResId` variable and I can tell you more

Comment: Am not using `<shape>` or `<layer-list>` also app runs fine when it is fresh installed. Crashes only when upgraded from previous version. 

[This is my iconResId](https://github.com/HarshNandwani/Digital-Tijori/blob/main/app/src/main/res/drawable/airtel_icon.xml)
and [this](https://github.com/HarshNandwani/Digital-Tijori/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/harshnandwani/digitaltijori/presentation/util/UpdateCompaniesOnAppStart.kt) is how I update resource ids on start of app.

Comment: try to change -1 in lines 37-38 to default image or 0. Something like `companyIconResIds.getResourceId(index, 0)` or `companyIconResIds.getResourceId(index, R.drawable.default_company_icon)`

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work. I think I found the root cause with this, even if am providing default as 0 or a default drawable, my DB isn't updating with it. It stays -1. I am passing updated Entity model to DAO's `@Update` method still don't know why it is not updating

Comment: I got it! App is crashing because the resource id is still of previous version (not getting updated because it taking id as 0 by default) Thanks for the help