# Jetpack Compose displaying Adaptive Icon Painter Resources: Only VectorDrawables and rasterized asset types are supported ex. PNG, JPG, WEBP

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-drawable, android-image, android-vectordrawable

I'm trying to display launcher icon of the app:

```
Image(
    modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp),
    painter = adaptiveIconPainterResource(id = R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round),
    contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name),
)
```

`adaptiveIconPainterResource()`:

```
@Composable
fun adaptiveIconPainterResource(@DrawableRes id: Int): Painter {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val res = context.resources
    val theme = context.theme

    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        // Android O supports adaptive icons, try loading this first (even though this is least likely to be the format).
        val adaptiveIcon = remember(id) {
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(res, id, theme) as? AdaptiveIconDrawable
        }
        if (adaptiveIcon != null) {
            remember(id) {
                BitmapPainter(adaptiveIcon.toBitmap().asImageBitmap())
            }
        } else {
            // We couldn't load the drawable as an Adaptive Icon, just use painterResource
            painterResource(id)
        }
    } else {
        // We're not on Android O or later, just use painterResource
        painterResource(id)
    }
}
```

It seems `ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(res, id, theme) as? AdaptiveIconDrawable` fails for some reason on this device so it just returns `null` and that's why it tries to use `painterResource` instead and crashes there because it's not for adaptive resources, only for vector drawable or usual image formats like (png, webp)

I tested it on real devices Android 6, 12-14

But at Firebase Crashlytics I saw a crash for Android 8.1:

[image]

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Only VectorDrawables and rasterized asset types are supported ex. PNG, JPG, WEBP
androidx.compose.ui.res.PainterResources_androidKt.loadVectorResource (PainterResources_android.kt:1299)

androidx.compose.ui.res.PainterResources_androidKt.painterResource (PainterResources_android.kt:1299)
com.hidden.design.components.ImagesKt.adaptiveIconPainterResource (Images.kt:150)
com.hidden.main.ComposableSingletons$MainScreenKt$lambda-1$1.invoke (MainScreen.kt:440)
```

I don't have a real device with Android 8.1 but I tested it on Pixel 2 Emulator with Android 8.1 and it works fine.

So what's exactly can be wrong here?

Mipmap:

[image]

Android Studio generates `webp` now instead of `png`, don't know if it can  be an issue, but it works for Samsung S5 on Android 6....

**Update**

I tried to use Glide Compose lib and it works fine for the same my devices and emulators:

```
GlideImage(
    modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp),
    model = R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round,
    transition = CrossFade,
    contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name),
)
```

I will try to use this code for release build and hope I won't get crashes as it was with `adaptiveIconPainterResource` function